# vim: multiple substitutions like sed

Tags: vim

Simply question,with sed is possible to do a multiple substitution

```
sed -e s/uno/due/ -e s/uno/due/
```

Is possible something similar with VIM internal substitution?

```
:'<,'>s/445/53/a/444/53/g
```

and

```
:'<,'>s/445/53/e/444/53/g
```

Doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`:'<,'>s/445/53/e | s/444/53/e`

This works by concatenating Ex commands using the pipe (`|`) symbol and using the `e` substitution flag (see: `:help :s_flags`) to avoid raising an error when the pattern cannot be found.