# vim multiple substitutions: three or more

Tags: vim

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202803/vim-multiple-substitutions-like-sed) solution works fine for two strings,but for three or more substitutions?
I have tried

```
:%s:one:two:e | s:three:four:e | s:five:six:e
```

But the third line on this example remain the same

```
one
two
three
five
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just forgot to place a `%` before your `s` command:

```
:%s:one:two:e | %s:three:four:e | %s:five:six:e
```

The `%` makes `vim` to search your whole text instead of just the current line.